# Change choice column after reaching certain date via JSON in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, json-formatting, json

I have a maintenance scheduler list with two inputs: MaintenanceStart (dateTime column) and Status (Choice column)

The predefined value in status column is 'Scheduled maintenance' and I would like to change it to 'Maintenance in progress' after I reach defined time in MaintenanceStart column.

Is it somehow possible with JSON and column formatting?

Thanks!

Comment: Column Formatting can be used to conditionally show the status message. BUT it's only a display value. If you want to actually update a Status field then formatting won't help you. If you can clarify if you are just looking for display customization or an actual update you're much more likely to get the answer you need. Thanks!

Comment: It can be also made as a display customization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going for the display route, you can accomplish this with column formatting!

You can apply this format to any column (it references your column by it's internal name of `MaintenanceStart`):

```
{
  "elmType": "span",
  "txtContent": "=if([$MaintenanceStart] >= @now, 'Scheduled maintenance', 'Maintenance in progress')"
}
```

This is a barebones format for sure (no styling) but that's the basic gist. With this approach the status column is not needed at all since you aren't actually setting a value.

There are tons of other samples that could help you take it further available here: https://github.com/pnp/list-formatting

You can also find a lot of video guidance here: http://bit.ly/lf-videos

Comment: Thanks! How about I want to change the design as well? Like this https://imgur.com/a/u8TUrwO